# Using ProDinner w/ areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor, prodinner

Has any had any success using ProDinner but by placing the Controllers in Areas? I tried and the Windsor IoC is not liking it.

I have not had any success finding info as to how to adjust ProDinner's Windsor Factory container configuration for Areas and would be appreciative if someone could offer up some solution.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer and I want to share with my fellow struggling .Net programmers, because **NO ONE WANTS TO PROVIDE FULL DOCUMENTATION BEYOND 'HELLO WORLD' EXAMPLES!!!!!! 

I mean, who does MVC sites without AREAS by and large these days????**

Only 1 step required and 1 Caution.

**Step 1: Register your areas before calling the bootstrapper:**

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); <--- INCLUDE THIS REGISTRATION HERE
        Bootstrapper.Bootstrap();
    }
```

**Caution 1: In _layout there is a HTML.Action to change theme pointing to the respective css files as such:** 
    < link href="@Url.Content("~")Content/themes/@Html.Action**("CurrentTheme", "ChangeTheme")**/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="demoStyle" />
    < link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/@Html.Action("CurrentTheme", "ChangeTheme")/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" id="jqStyle" /> 
    < link href="@Url.Content("~")Content/themes/@Html.Action("CurrentTheme", "ChangeTheme")/AwesomeMvc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="aweStyle" />

Make sure where the lines that read: ("CurrentTheme", "ChangeTheme"), are changed to: 
**("CurrentTheme", "ChangeTheme", new { area = "Insert Your Area Name Here" })**

Comment: thank you much! And I agree, you cannot real real world help beyond simple non-real scenarios.